# CakePHPのedit機能が上手くいかない！！

Tags: php, cakephp

はじめまして！

CakePHPのedit機能を利用して、プロフィールの編集画面を実装しようとしている者です。

以下のコードを使用すると、 
①編集画面に、既に登録されている名前やメリット等の情報が出てこない。 
②保存をすると、ユーザーid(user_id)が「0」になってしまい、本来のユーザーidが格納されない。

普通のeditコードと違う点は、編集するidデータをAuthコンポーネントから利用している点のみです。

どうすれば正常に機能出来るでしょうか? 
是非ご指導のほどよろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
//ProfilesController.php
   public function edit() {

     $user = AuthComponent::user('id');
     $this->Profile->user_id = $user;

     if ($this->request->is('get')) {
         $this->request->data = $this->Profile->read(); //①編集画面に、既に登録されている名前やメリット等の情報が出てこない
     } else { 
         if ($this->Profile->save($this->request->data)) {  //②保存をすると、ユーザーid(user_id)が「0」になってしまい、本来のユーザーidが格納されない。
             $this->Session->setFlash('Success!');
             $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
         } else {
             $this->Session->setFlash('Failed!');
         }
     }
   }

//edit.ctp
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Profile', array('action'=>'edit'));
echo $this->Form->input('name');
echo $this->Form->input('merit');
echo $this->Form->input('career');
echo $this->Form->end('保存');
?>
```

Comment: `Profile`モデルの内容と`profiles`テーブルの定義も追記していただけると正確な回答ができるかと思います。

Comment: profilesテーブルの主キーはなんですか？Profileモデルの$primaryKey設定はどうなっていますか？そこがわからないと回答できません。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/12779

Answer (score 1):

はじめのProfileデータの読み込みを下記のようにすべきです。

```
$profile = $this->Profile->find('first', ['Profile.user_id'=>$user_id]);
```

そして、(1)を

```
$this->request->data = $profile;
```

とし、(2)のときは

```
$this->request->data['Profile']['user_id'] = $profile['Profile']['user_id'];
```

とすべきです。

(1)
Model::read()では遅延読み込みは行われません。
代わりにfalseが返ってきているのではないでしょうか。

Model::read()は必ず第1引数またはModel::$idが決まっていないと
何もせずにfalseを返すようになっています。

$this->request->dataがfalseなので、$this->Formで使われていない状態になっています。

(2)
Model::save()ではModel::$idが先に得られ、
でも$this->request->data['Profile']['user_id']がないので、
結果的に該当idの行の'user_id'が0として保存されてしまいます。

サンプルでは'hidden'か何かで$this->Formに'user_id'が分かっていたか、
上記のようにModel::save()の直前で強制的に代入していたのではないでしょうか？